# Class declaration Header - HTML 5

Tags: css, class, html, header

I was trying to put a image (logo) in the header element provided by HTML5 and I am curious if anyone knows if it is possible to declare a class in CSS something on the lines of `header.image`?

I tried `header.image` and it didn't seem to work, however as soon as I had the class named just `.headerimage` then it seem to be picking up the padding property I was trying to apply.

I'm doing some very basic learning as it's been sometime I picked up HTML code. Please help if your time permits. Thanks

I was trying to put a image (logo) in the header element provided by HTML5 and I am curious if anyone knows if it is possible to declare a class in CSS something on the lines of `header.image`?

I tried `header.image` and it didn't seem to work, however as soon as I had the class named just `.headerimage` then it seem to be picking up the padding property I was trying to apply.

I'm doing some very basic learning as it's been sometime I picked up HTML code. Please help if your time permits. Thanks

This is not the entire HTML/CSScode, but I could manage to take some screenshots. You guys helped me answer some questions and understand how period is not relevant to what I was trying to do. 
Screenshot 1: https://skitch.com/android86/fm4r7/dreamweaver  ( HTML design view)                     Screenshot 2: https://skitch.com/android86/fm4fd/dreamweaver ( CSS)

In the screenshot 1, I tried to have the links for website Contact and Login as a part of the Nav tag provided by html 5, however I wanted these to be horizontally next to the hgroup. I assigned a width to hgroup and now I have a lot of space to the right of hgroup however the nav is starting to line up horizontally, is this something I should handle with position or float property in CSS? I tried both in various combinations, I assigned a width to nav in order to fit in the area however it doesn't seems to be working. Any clue? The CSS code is in screenshot 2. After looking at the discussion here I thought using class might not be required instead rather parent child relation might be most relevant. I personally thought and read that one should use id's in CSS when it is a very unique scenario and class when we expect to use a certain thing very commonly, is this parent child relation a way of declaring a class? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please provide your markup and css.

Comment: I tried to update the existing post with some code snapshots and some comments as it wouldn't let me paste the entire code for some reason. Maybe I don't know how to use this site well enough. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't use period in class names, because it is a class selector. For example, is you have a class "foo" applied to some html element, you can style this element in css linking to it as ".foo".

Example HTML:

```
<header class="foo">
  <img class="bar" src="some/path/here">
  Some content here
</header>
```

Example CSS:

```
.foo { color: #AAA; }
```

or

```
header.foo { color: #AAA; }
```

In first CSS example the style will be applyed to all elements, wich have class "foo". In the second - to all elements, wich have class "foo" and same time are of "header" type.

Returning to your case, I think the only aim is to apply style to image inside of header element. It can be done different ways:

1. Use the image class

   ```
   .bar { width: 100px; }
   ```

   or more concretely

   ```
   img.bar { width: 100px; }
   ```
2. Use parent-child relations

   ```
   header img { width: 100px; }
   ```

   above will apply styles wich lay inside the header element or in its
   children elements

   ```
   header>img { width: 100px; }
   ```

   this will be ok only for the direct child of header.
3. Combine two approaches.

If you know for shure that there will be only one image in header element, I can recommend the approach with ">". Read more about different css selectors, ids and classes. It will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS, a period without spaces like `this.thing` means:

select elements that have the class `thing` but only if they are of type `this`

Period (.) is a special character in CSS, so you can't name classes with periods.  Try an `_` or a `-`.

Comment: A period `.` is called a class selector. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html

Comment: "so you can't name classes with periods" The HTML5 spec doesn't say this.

Comment: @BoltClock this has nothing to do with HTML5, this is CSS. [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) "In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_)"

Comment: @rockerest: The next sentence starts, "Identifiers can also contain escaped characters" You can still include a period in your class and select it, provided the period is escaped as `\.`, and have your stylesheet still validate. The next bullet point expands on this further.

Comment: @BoltClock so you're saying "you can't name classes with periods, you can name them with `\.`."  There is a distinct difference.  You still can never include a period in a class name.  `\.` is an effectively different character when it's parsed.  I'm not sure if you're trolling, or if you're really so anal that the very inclusion of the visual representation of a period has set you off on this syntactical hair-splitting adventure, but for all intents and purposes including a period in a class name is impossible.  Again, `.` and `\.` are different strings for naming.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your markup looks like this:

```
<header><img /></header>
```

The selector you want would be this:

```
header img {...}
```

If you really did class your image with class="image" (kinda redundant), then you'd want:

```
header .image {...} /* note space */
```

This assumes that the browser supports the html header element. If it doesn't, you'd want to use something like html5shim [1](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) or modernizer [2](http://www.modernizr.com/)